# dax comparison operations do not support comparing values of type text

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]
please help me my power bi does not support this type of command dax comparison operations do not support comparing values of type text  (*************************************************************************************************)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Power Query and change the type of AnnualIncome column to Number